# Numbers interpreted as sets and functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

In set theory numbers are defined as sets
$$\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\},\dots$$
where $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$ and $n-1=\bigcup_{k\in n}k, \; n\ne\emptyset$. As I remember there are some complicated formulas for $m+n$ and $m\cdot n$ but I don't know how to get them and would like some hints.

Also, is there a canonical way to interpret a number $k\in\{0,\dots, n^m-1\}$ as a function 
$m\to n$? I'll guess $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are trivial, but the rest?

Comment: $m+n$, $m\cdot n$, and $m^n$ on ordinals are all defined by recursion. That is, there is a unique function $+$ on $\omega\times\omega$ that satisfies $m+(n+1)=(m+n)+1$ and $m+0=m$ (where $x+1$ is the successor operation), and we define it using this uniqueness property.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I guess that's the way set theorists do it, but I'm looking for something more exiting for recreational purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it with ordinal arithmetic, which means defining the properties by induction and using the induction theorem. Or you can do it with cardinal arithmetic:

$$m+n=k\iff \exists f\colon m\times\{0\}\cup n\times\{1\}\to k\text{ a bijection}$$

Then you just need to show that $k$ is unique, which essentially means showing that the natural numbers are Dedekind finite, and this can be shown using induction.